# Six angles of a triangle whose sum of the angles gives three?

Tags: trigonometry

Normally:

> $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$ for all angles of a right triangles

For all sort of triangles there is the sum:

> $\sin^2 A+\sin^2 B+\sin^2 C+\cos^2 A+\cos^2 B+\cos^2 C=3$

Why would the measures of six angles give a result of three?

Comment: I'd suggest considering changing the title as it's confusing. As for the question, $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$ is an identity which holds true for all $\theta$. The answer to your question is that it holds exactly because of that. There is nothing special about this result.

Comment: @Shuri2060 I was taught that the identity holds for  a right angle triangle only .

Comment: Perhaps the explanation for why the identity holds was done using right angled triangles. However, it actually holds in general.

Comment: I'm not even sure what that would mean as there's only one angle involved, $\theta$, and the only special angle on a right triangle is $\pi/2$. The other angles could be any value.

Answer (score 2):

The identity $ \sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1 $ is true for any theta. It's not particularly bound to any triangle. So group your second identity,

$$ (\sin^2A + \cos^2A) + (\sin^2B + \cos^2B) + (\sin^2C + \cos^2C) = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3 $$

In regards to your confusion, $\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$, is called the pythagorean identity, which is perhaps why you associated it with right triangles, but it holds for any $\theta$.

Comment: It is, in fact, using the regular Pythagorean theorem on a right triangle with hypotenuse equal to $1$.